# How to Change textLabel property in UIButton programmatically in iOS?

Tags: ios, uibutton, label, title

I have a `UIButton` that should have 2 statuses - "Play" and "Pause"; i.e. - at the first time the user sees it it says "Play" and then whenever the user clicks it it should switch between "Play" and "Pause".

I managed to create the controller itself - the content is played and paused properly - but I cannot seem to change the UIButton Text Label text.

I use:

```
myButton.titleLabel.text = @"Play";

myButton.titleLabel.text = @"Pause";
```

It's not working. The text is not changing. I also tried [myButton.titleLabel setText:@"Pause"] and it's not working as well.

How can I set it?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It should be:

```
[myButton setTitle:@"Play" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

You need to pass the `state` as well. You can check other `state`'s [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIControlState).

You can then do something like this:

```
[myButton setTitle:@"Play" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setTitle:@"Stop" forState: UIControlStateSelected];
```

Answer (score 9):

**SWIFT 4**

```
myButton.setTitle("Pause", for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this to be somewhat out of date since attributed strings were added. Apparently titles of buttons assigned in a storyboard are attributed strings. Attributed titles take precedence over NSString titles, so if you want to use a simple string as a title you have to remove the attributed title first. I did as below, though there may be a better way. You could, of course, make your new title also an attributed string.

```
[myButton setAttributedTitle: nil     forState: 0xffff];
[myButton           setTitle: @"Play" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you want to load it on page load, and support localized language:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if (self.flagToChangeLabel){
        NSString* newBtnTitle = NSLocalizedString(@"LOCALIZED_KEY", nil);
        [self.laterButton setTitle:newBtnTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.laterButton setTitle:newBtnTitle forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    }
}
```